# Movimiento de cámara Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tengo la siguiente situación.

Intento que la cámara siga el personaje, sin embargo la cámara queda estática.

Este es el video con el error: https://youtu.be/8I4l9cKJHLQ

1. El script esta asignado a la cámara.
2. La consola no muestra ningún error en el código.
3. El tag esta creado y asignado correctamente.

Muchas Gracias

El código es este:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SmoothFollow : MonoBehaviour{
    
public float xMargin = 1.0f;
public float yMargin = 1.0f;
public float xSmooth = 10.0f;
public float ySmooth = 10.0f;
public Vector2 maxXandY;
public Vector2 minXandY;
public Transform cameraTarget;

void awake(){
    cameraTarget = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("CameraTarget").transform;
}

    bool CheckXMargin(){
        return Mathf.Abs (transform.position.x - cameraTarget.position.x) > xMargin;
    }
    bool CheckYMargin(){
        return Mathf.Abs (transform.position.y - cameraTarget.position.y) > xMargin;
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
    }
    void FixedUpdate(){
        TrackPlayer();
    }
    void TrackPlayer(){
        float TargetX = transform.position.x;
        float TargetY = transform.position.y;

        if (CheckXMargin ()){
            TargetX = Mathf.Lerp (transform.position.x, cameraTarget.position.x, xSmooth * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (CheckYMargin ()){
            TargetY = Mathf.Lerp (transform.position.y, cameraTarget.position.y, ySmooth * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        TargetX = Mathf.Clamp (TargetX, minXandY.x, maxXandY.x);
        TargetY = Mathf.Clamp (TargetY, minXandY.y, maxXandY.y);

        transform.position = new Vector3 (TargetX, TargetY, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías considerar usar Cinemachine.

Comment: Hola Mateo, Pues era bastante sencillo no había asignado como hijo en camera target como hijo del Player, por eso no se ejecutaba.  muchas gracias